# Python/Cython adding to dictionary is bottleneck

Tags: python, cython

I have a computationally expensive loop to get through in Python. In total, I am looping around 2 million times, and each time am adding a new key to a growing dictionary with a list as the value. I.e.,

```
for i in xrange(600):
    d = {}

    for i in xrange(3200):
        # execute some logic
        ...

        # add to dict
        new_key = "some-str"
        d[new_key] = [0.0, 1.0, 2.0]

    # do some other stuff
    ...
```

I've profiled my code, and the operation where I'm adding the new key + list to the dictionary is a huge bottleneck. That single operation is taking up ~18% of the execution time at `1e-06` seconds per operation.

Is there a way I can speed this operation up in Cython/Python? I've tried changing `d` to a defaultdict, but that was slower. I also tried different list operations like `.extend` but the above implementation is the fastest approach I've been able to find.

Comment: I can suggest you to use tuple instead of list
`d[new_key] = (0.0, 1.0, 2.0,)` because tuple is immutable garbage collector will not track it and this can improve your speed

Comment: `cython` still has to use Python calls to add to a dictionary.  Don't go that route just to because of this operation.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. @hpaulj what would be a better data structure to use for storing this data?

Answer (score 1):

So here's an iterative creation of a dictionary:

```
In [5]: adict = {}
In [6]: for i in range(4):
   ...:     adict[i] = list(range(i,i+4))
In [7]: adict
Out[7]: {0: [0, 1, 2, 3], 1: [1, 2, 3, 4], 2: [2, 3, 4, 5], 3: [3, 4, 5, 6]}
```

In numeric `numpy` work we often recommend appending values to a list, and making the array from it at the end.  A dictionary equivalent is:

```
In [8]: alist = []
In [9]: for i in range(4):
   ...:     alist.append((i, list(range(i,i+4))))
In [10]: alist
Out[10]: [(0, [0, 1, 2, 3]), (1, [1, 2, 3, 4]), (2, [2, 3, 4, 5]), (3, [3, 4, 5, 6])]
In [11]: dict(alist)
Out[11]: {0: [0, 1, 2, 3], 1: [1, 2, 3, 4], 2: [2, 3, 4, 5], 3: [3, 4, 5, 6]}
```

Doing some timings with Ipython timeit.

First the direct iterative dictionary:

```
In [12]: %%timeit
    ...: adict = {}
    ...: for i in range(1000):
    ...:    adict[i] = list(range(i,i+4))
    ...: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.67 ms per loop
```

The list append is basically the same time:

```
In [13]: %%timeit
    ...: alist = []
    ...: for i in range(1000):
    ...:    alist.append((i,list(range(i,i+4))))

1000 loops, best of 3: 1.79 ms per loop
```

Adding the `dict(alist)` is a minor increase in time

```
In [14]: %%timeit
    ...: alist = []
    ...: for i in range(1000):
    ...:    alist.append((i,list(range(i,i+4))))
    ...: adict = dict(alist)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.93 ms per loop
```

It appears that if you need to create values in a loop, it doesn't matter a whole lot whether you collect them in a dictionary or a list.

If you already have a suitable list, converting that to a dictionary is fast.  But it doesn't pay to create the list as an intermediate step.

Dictionary `update` is also a good way of adding a lot of values to a dictionary - but you need the source dictionary first.

Comment: Thanks for this. I agree I haven't been able to find a much better way to add values in a loop. Dicts/Lists are comparable as you pointed out.